# Celery daemon spawning multiple processes for single worker with systemd

Tags: django, celery, systemd, celerybeat

I'm trying to use django with celery & celerybeat to run periodic tasks. I have my celery process setup with systemd as

```
[Unit]
Description=my celery daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid
Type=forking
User=myuser
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=celery
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0770
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp/
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/celery multi start worker1 \
    --app=myapp \
    --concurrency=1 \
    --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule \
    --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid \
    --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log \
    --loglevel=INFO \
    --beat
ExecStop=/opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/celery multi stopwait worker1 \
    --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid \
    --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log \
ExecReload=/opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/celery multi restart worker1 \
    --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid \
    --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log \

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This all works fine.. but I notice it spawns 3/4 processes despite there being only 1 worker, and concurrency being set to 1. Why is this? My goal is to have 1 worker running that will queue tasks up, rather than perform them synchronously for now.

`$ ps aux | grep celery`:

```
myuser    1748  0.6 11.8 189816 59400 ?        S    11:59   0:01 /opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/python -m celery worker --beat --concurrency=1 --app=myapp --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid --hostname=worker1@staging
myuser    1753  1.2 11.9 272324 59528 ?        Sl   11:59   0:02 /opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/python -m celery worker --beat --concurrency=1 --app=myapp --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid --hostname=worker1@staging
myuser    1754  0.0 11.4 197540 57244 ?        S    11:59   0:00 /opt/myapp/.virtualenv/bin/python -m celery worker --beat --concurrency=1 --app=myapp --schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/opt/myapp/log/celery.log --pidfile=/var/run/celery/celery.pid --hostname=worker1@staging
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using 'multi' instead of 'worker'?

Comment: I was under the impression that `worker` couldn't be deamonised? I did initially try using worker but I would get a timeout on systemd start,

Comment: As an theoretical exercise, how could I modify this to use worker and still support start/stopwait/restart etc?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, check if you can daemonize the worker with celery worker -D. Oh, and if you plan to do lots of I/O, don't use eventlet if you needn't, I fixed a bug today that haunted us for weeks that was caused by eventlet (solution: we switched to gevent).

Comment: If you are deamonising worker be sure to remove the "Type=forking"